# How to add an outline/stroke around a material-ui icon?

Tags: svg, icons, material-design, material-ui

How to add a color outline around the material-ui icons?
Have this

[image]

Look more like this?

[image]

I've tried stroke and webkit-stroke and no luck on anything. It put a border around the whole invisible box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Material-UI with React the way to go, in theory, should be setting the property `stroke` and `stroke-width` directly to the imported heart icon. But as you said, it will create an awkward border around the whole svg tag.
Then, you should be able to extract the  definition of the heart from the dom and use the more general `SvgIcon` component Material-UI provides.

So, to reach your goal, instead of:

```
import { Favorite } from '@material-ui/icons';
export default () => <Favorite stroke={"white"} stroke-width={1}/>
```

I would go for:

```
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
export default () => (
  <SvgIcon>
    <path
      d="M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z"
      stroke="white"
      strokeWidth={1}
    />
  </SvgIcon>
);
```